# Redirect to 404 page from forbidden page when url has only extension without page name

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am facing 403 error forbidden message when accessing no page name with extension.
Ex. `http://loremipsum.lorem/.html` shows `403 forbidden.`

Used in `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteRule \.html$ - [R=404,L]
```

Also used

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ test.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Whenever anyone tries to access `/.html` or `/.htm` or `/.php` in `url`, web page should be redirected to `404` page or any custom page (set any custom page instead of default error page).

Answer (score 0):

/.html or /.htm or /.php are not valid addresses, so set `ErrorDocument 404 /404.html` in your .htaccess file and create /404.html file with your custom error message.

Comment: Already added ErrorDocument 404 /404.html this in .htaccess file. But I am getting the 403 Forbidden error page.

Comment: If you request change-to-your-domain.com/any-non-exist-adress in browser then you get a 404 error page?

Comment: Url - my-domain.com/.html 
Getting result 403 Forbidden message